# How to find if page is_home in WP theme functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this code to add some meta boxes to the home page in Wordpress (which is ID 6):

```
function add_page_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box('meta_p_sub', 'Page Subtitle', 'meta_p_sub', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'];
    if ($post_id == '6') {
        add_meta_box('meta_hp_thing', 'Homepage Thing', 'meta_hp_thing', 'page', 'normal', 'low');
    }
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_page_metaboxes');
```

I want to be able to use this on several sites, and the ID won't always be '6'. I've tried to use `if (is_home()) {...` and `if (is_front_page()) {...` but that doesn't seems to work.

How can I find out which ID is set in WP Admin > Settings > Reading > Front Page and use that?

Cheers!
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Front page ID is stored in `page_on_front` option.

```
$post_id = get_option( 'page_on_front')
```

Comment: Great, thanks. So I'll get $post_id as I was, and then do `if ($post_id == get_option('page_on_front')) {..`. Perfect

Comment: By the way, you can check `show_on_front` option. `if (get_option('show_on_front') === 'page') { ... }` It value will be `page` if you select page in Settings > Reading > Front Page.

Answer (score -2):

As an alternative you could use is_page( 'slug' );

```
if( is_page( 'homepage ) )
{
  // Do your thing...
}
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seem to work as I'm not sure the homepage has a slug. Also I'm not sure these theme functions (like is_home()) are available in the backend to functions.php. I'm using the `get_option('page_on_front')` suggestion as it's portable. Thanks.